# No more lock classes available from transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am getting this error

> No more lock classes available from transaction.. Error 1220. SQLSTATE 42000. Severity 17. MsgState 1. Line 1.

when I execute this select

```
SELECT me.Id, dbo.getMenuName(me.id)[name]  FROM BSMenus me
```

this is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Getmenuname(@id INTEGER) 
returns VARCHAR(100) AS 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE @res VARCHAR(100) 
  SELECT @res= 
         CASE 
                WHEN Isnull(m.bsmenufatherid,'')='' THEN m.NAME 
                ELSE dbo.Getmenuname(m.bsmenufatherid)+' / '+m.NAME 
         END 
  FROM   bsmenus m 
  WHERE  m.id=@id 
  RETURN @res; 
END
go
```

Comment: there was a connect item raised  for this,but  the function has recursion and i dont see your function doing the same.can you please share table data for us to test the issue

Comment: Are u looping any sql statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hit the maximum recursion level, which is **32** for SQL Server 2008 and above. You can check the current recursion level using [@@NESTLEVEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/nestlevel-transact-sql) variable.  Either there is a mistake in your recursion logic or you will have to rewrite the code without recursion.

See here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/nestlevel-transact-sql