# Get Hieararchical data as JSON from SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, hierarchy

I have following table:

| Id | HieararchyId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | / | MHz |
| 2 | /1/ | Finance |
| 3 | /1/ | IT |
| 4 | /1/3/ | Software Development |
| 5 | /1/3/ | QA |
| 6 | /1/2/ | Accountant |

and I want to get data for my [TreeView](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/) like:

```
[
{
  "Id": 1,
  "HierarchyId": "/"
  "Name":"MHz",
  "Children":[
     {
        "Id": 3,
        "HierarchyId": "/1/"
        "Name":"IT",
        "Children":[
           {
              "Id": 4,
              "HierarchyId": "/1/3/"
              "Name":"Software Development",
              "Children":[]
           }
           {
              "Id": 5,
              "HierarchyId": "/1/3/"
              "Name":"QA",
              "Children":[]
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "Id": 2,
        "HierarchyId": "/1/"
        "Name":"Finance",
        "Children":[
           {
              "Id": 6,
              "HierarchyId": "/1/2/"
              "Name":"Accountant",
              "Children":[]
           }
        ]
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

I tried with this: [How to generate hierarchical JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38298659/17612995)

Got **error**: [No more lock classes available from transaction.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45230504/17612995)

Or is it better creating recursive function and filling the `Tree` on `client side`?

**Update**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetJson (@departmentId hierarchyid)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS BEGIN
RETURN (
    SELECT
      Id,
      HierarchyId,
      Name,
      children = JSON_QUERY(dbo.GetJson(HierarchyId))
    FROM Departments p
    WHERE p.HierarchyId.IsDescendantOf(@departmentId ) = 1
    FOR JSON PATH
);
END;
```

Comment: Is your error meant to be a hyperlink? The URL is `https://No%20more%20lock%20classes%20available%20from%20transaction.` which isn't a valid URL.

Comment: Why do `Finance` and `IT` share the same `HierarchyId` ?

Comment: updated url. @Luuk because they are both departments. Actually it doesnt mater, let's say they have different `/1/1/` finance and `/1/2/` IT

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69696666/14868997 The only reasonable solution I ever found was a recursive function. In your case just modify it to get the descendants using a join with `.IsDescendantOf()`

Comment: Does this absolutely have to be done within SQL? This is likely going to be easier if you export the raw data and generate the JSON within a procedural language in your application layer

Comment: @Charlieface yes it's relevant, I have already did but getting error: `No more lock classes available from transaction.` . Seems SQL Server has limitation on recrusive calls

Comment: To check "is a mistake in your recursion logic" we need to see your SQL...

Comment: Unfortunately `IsDescendantOf` returns the current node also, so you need to exclude that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I have found to do this is to use a recursive function.

You can self-join all nodes and check if they are a child using `GetAncestor`

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetJson (@parentID hierarchyid)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT
          t.Id,
          t.HierarchyId,
          t.Name,
          children = JSON_QUERY(dbo.GetJson(t.HierarchyId))
        FROM Tree t
        WHERE t.HierarchyId <> @parentID
          AND t.HierarchyId.GetAncestor(1) = @parentID
        FOR JSON PATH
    );
END;

go
```

```
SELECT dbo.GetJson(hierarchyid::GetRoot());
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2aca284506e12c1b6fb6ea46fcd3da7a)

**Result**

```json
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "HierarchyId": "/1/",
    "Name": "MHz",
    "children": [
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "HierarchyId": "/1/2/",
        "Name": "Finance",
        "children": [
          {
            "Id": 6,
            "HierarchyId": "/1/2/6/",
            "Name": "Accountant"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": 3,
        "HierarchyId": "/1/3/",
        "Name": "IT",
        "children": [
          {
            "Id": 4,
            "HierarchyId": "/1/3/4/",
            "Name": "Software Development"
          },
          {
            "Id": 5,
            "HierarchyId": "/1/3/5/",
            "Name": "QA"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the taking your time and helping me! What I was missing, exluding current node.

Comment: I need one more suggestion if you are available. I was adding `HieararchyId` like this way: `{HieararchyId = ParentHieararchyId  + ParentId + "/", Name = IT}` that's why I'm getting same `HieararchyId` for both `IT` and `Finance` (Their parent is same). I'm doing this way because values are dinamically available for me.

Comment: Unclear what you mean, but perhaps you should update your question with the real data, or even better create a new question for this

Comment: @Maruf - what if you incorporate the current row's ID into it's hierarchyid? For example, QA would be /1/3/5/

Comment: @Maruf Try https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b6550699e4a49317fa74e637406487df

Comment: @BenThul that's the target, but before insertion QA id:5 isn't available for me, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe. If ID is generated via a database sequence object you can use the sequence explicitly and use the value for both the ID and the HierarchyID. If it's an identity column you can either use an after insert trigger to update the column to be the right thing or create a computed column that concatenates the current HierarchyID column and the ID.

Comment: @BenThul achieved using Trigger could not find better solution.

Comment: @Charlieface can we exlcude last three: `{id:4, Name:}, {id:5, Name:}, {id:6, Name:}` ?Because we have already displayed them as a child nodes

Comment: Ok have modified a bit. But your main issue is that the hierarchy values are not correct. You should not have multiple rows with the same value. Instead store each one concatenated with its ID. See new fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2aca284506e12c1b6fb6ea46fcd3da7a